# Laravel : connect to sybase server CentOS 6.7

Tags: laravel, centos, odbc, sybase, freetds

I am trying to connect to a Sybase Server with **Laravel (PHP 5.6)** on a **CentOS 6.7**.

I already installed `freetds` and `unixODBC`:

```
sudo yum install freetds unixODBC
```

And managed to connect with `tsql` in command line:

```
TDSVER=5.0 tsql -H ServerName -p 1234 -U username
```

I configured:

**/etc/freetds.conf**

```
[ServerName]
    host = ServerName 
    port = 1234
    tds version = 5.0
```

**/etc/odbc.ini**
* note that libtdsodbc.so.0.0.0 is the file I am seeing in /usr/lib64

```
[ServerName]
    Driver = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0.0.0 
    Trace = No
    Server = ServerName 
    Database = DBName
    Port = 1234
    TDS_Version = 5.0
```

When I connect with Laravel, I tried:

```
$db = new \PDO("dblib:host=ServerName;port=1234;dbname=DBName", "UserName", "Pwd");
```

And

```
$db = new PDO('odbc:Driver=FreeTDS; Server=ServerName; Port=1234; Database=DBName; UID=UserName; PWD=Pwd;');
```

And

```
't20fx' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => 'ServerName',
        'port'      => 1234,
        'database' => 'DBName',
        'username' => 'UserName',
        'password' => 'Pwd',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],
```

I get everytime the `could not find driver` error... How could I connect Laravel to Sybase (I hate this old technology...)??

[image]